# Cannot extract class values

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape information from this website:
"https://www.privateproperty.co.za/for-sale/western-cape/cape-town/55"

Specifically, I have an issue with trying to obtain number of bedrooms, bathrooms and garages.

Right now, I get index out of the range error and I am not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

```
       for prop in response.css('div.resultsItemsContainer a'):
           link = 'https://www.privateproperty.co.za' + prop.css('::attr(href)').get()
           title = prop.css('div.title::text').get()
           price = prop.css('div.priceDescription::text').re(r'\d+')

           bedrooms, bathrooms, garages = None, None, None
           for i in range(len(prop.css('div.features.row div::attr(class)'))):
               counter = i - 1
               if prop.css('div.features.row div::attr(class)')[i].get() == 'icon bedroom':
                   bedrooms = prop.css('div.features.row div::text')[counter].get()
               elif prop.css('div.features.row div::attr(class)')[i].get() == 'icon bathroom':
                   bathrooms = prop.css('div.features.row div::text')[counter].get()
               elif prop.css('div.features.row div::attr(class)')[i].get() == 'icon garage':
                   garages = prop.css('div.features.row div::text')[counter].get()
```

Example error:

```
    garages = prop.css('div.features.row div::text')[counter].get()
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: I don't see any matches for .resultsItemsContainer at that url.

Comment: @QHarr Presumably there are matches, or the outer `for` loop wouldn't run at all.

Comment: @JohnGordon Agreed but kinda wondering how we might test based on info provided.

Comment: @JohnGordon I provided the sample error, some of the properties do not have all the features.

Comment: As a first step in debugging, you could print `prop.css('div.features.row div::text')` to see if it looks like you expect.

Comment: Or just skip the feature if the length of `prop.css(...)` is less than `counter`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks, that solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy with XPath:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="feature"][contains(., "Baths")]/span/text()').get()
```